# Nginx or Varnish caching with multiple versions of a site

Tags: nginx, http, cache

I have a website (https://mediacru.sh) that has a few versions. There's the normal desktop site, the same site with a dark theme, and the mobile site. They all share the same URLs. The theme is selected with a cookie and the mobile version is shown based on the user agent.

I've set up caching as seen [here in our nginx config](https://github.com/MediaCrush/MediaCrush/blob/master/config/nginx.conf). We can get upwards of 500 requests per second and I need to keep a lot of that traffic away from our backend so everything stays healthy. I've set it up with a 1 or 30 second cache (depending on which part of the site is being cached), but this has the unfortunate side-effect of caching one user's page and serving the wrong page to someone else.

What can I do to adjust the caching to recognize these different situations as unique? We previously had Varnish set up between nginx and the backend, but we didn't do anything special with it. Would it perhaps be able to suit our needs?

Comment: Yiu could set different cookies for different types of client and use that cookie in proxy_cache_key

Comment: How could I set the cookie on the first hit? Could I force a cache miss if no cookie is set?

Comment: This is on your devs, but your site should *not* be doing user-agent sniffing to detect mobile devices; there is a continuum of screen sizes in use these days. You should use CSS media queries to detect which version of a site to show. See http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Comment: We are fully aware of how CSS media queries work, but the differences we need are so dramatic that an entirely different version is justified. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example implementation using cookie. If cookie value one of `dark`, `light` or `mobile` we try to serve cached page. For any other cookie value (including no value) we bypass cache and suppose that upstream will set appropriate cookie so next request will use cache.

We use `proxy_cache_key` to add cookie value to cache key and `proxy_cache_bypass` to skip cache if cookie is not in set of predefined values.

```
map $cookie_theme $cache_bypass {
    default "1";
    "dark"      "0";
    "light"     "0";
    "mobile"    "0";
}

proxy_cache_path /var/tmp/nginx levels=1 keys_zone=test-cache:10m;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test-cache.localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://test-cache;

        proxy_cache test-cache;
        proxy_cache_valid 1m;
        proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri $cookie_theme";
        proxy_cache_bypass $cache_bypass;
    }
}
```

Manuals:

- http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_key
- http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_bypass
- http://nginx.org/r/map

Comment: Thanks, I think that'll do what we need! I'll follow up with comments if I run into trouble.